# Toggle Icon Framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a icon and I want to change it on every click
here is my

```js
$$('.right').on('click', function() {
  $$("#change-view").html() === '<i id="" class="material-icons">view_column</i>' ? $$("#change-view").html('<i id="" class="material-icons">view_carousel</i>') : $$("#change-view").html('<i id="" class="material-icons">view_column</i>');
})
```

```html
<div class="right"><a href="#" id="change-view" class="link"><i class="icon 
material-icons">view_carousel</i></a></div>
```

NOTE: It only works on first click but after that it does not change anymore
      I am using double ($$) for Framework7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var $$ = $.noConflict();
$$('.right').on('click', function() {
  $$("#change-view").html() === '<i id="" class="material-icons">view_column</i>' ? $$("#change-view").html('<i id="" class="material-icons">view_carousel</i>') : $$("#change-view").html('<i id="" class="material-icons">view_column</i>');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right"><a href="#" id="change-view" class="link"><i class="icon 
material-icons">view_carousel</i></a></div>
```

Hope this will help you.